# Splitting list element into individual single elements in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

currently I have two list, ListofComments and ListofWords. ListofComments has many words in its element. For example.
ListofComments[0] = 'I love python'
ListofComments[1] = 'I hate python'
but currently i was able to only split it into individual words for the last element of ListofComments. Below is what I have currently.

```
 for x in range(0, 58196):
    ListofWords = (re.sub("[^\w]", " ", ListofComments[x]).split())
```

I understand that perhaps another loop is needed but i can't exactly pinpoint how to go about solving this issue. The desire output would be having these ListofWords[0] = 'I' ListofWords[1] = 'love' ListofWords[2] = 'python' ListofWords[3] = 'I' LstofWords[4] = 'hate' ListofWords[5] = 'python'

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: You're overwriting `ListofWords` each iteration. You need `ListofWords` to be a list and assign its elements like `ListOfWords.append(<list of words>)`. It'll be a list of lists in the end.

Comment: Use `for x in range(len(ListofComments)):` or you will come to grief with `list out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your only problem is you're overwriting your `ListofWords` at every loop iteration, hence why at the end of the loop you only see words from the last element of `ListofComments`.

Try this:

```
ListofWords = []
for x in range(0, 58196):
    ListofWords.extend(re.sub("[^\w]", " ", ListofComments[x]).split())
```

EDIT:

As others suggested, you want to make sure you avoid a `list out of range` error. I didn't want to change the rest of your code, just to make evident what had to be changed, for it to work as you expected.
A simpler (and more robust) way to write the above, would be:

```
ListofWords = []
for comment in ListofComments:
    ListofWords.extend(re.sub("[^\w]", " ", comment).split())
```

Comment: I saw @ivan_pozdeev reply after I posted this; I'm suggesting basically the same, except for one thing: if you use `extend` you'll have every word saved in a single, one-dimensional list; if you `append` to the list, you'll end up with a list of lists. What you need depends on how you plan to use `ListofWords` later in your code

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, this would solve your problem:

```
list_of_words = []
my_list = ["i love python3", "i hate python2"]

for sentence in my_list:
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        list_of_words.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has two problems:

- `ListofWords` is overrwritten on every iteration
- you may run out of range

Here's my solution

```
from functools import reduce

# split comments
split_comments = [re.sub("[^\w]", " ", c).split() for c in ListofComments]
# >>> [['I', 'love', 'python'], ['I', 'hate', 'python']]

# flatten list of lists
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, split_comments)
# >>> ['I', 'love', 'python', 'I', 'hate', 'python']
```